# Javascript variable issue

Tags: javascript

why does this

http://jsfiddle.net/BkGxq/1/

return "$undefined" ?

if i dont do

```
 level_prices['f'.i] = i;
```

and do

```
 level_prices[i] = i;
```

it works, (i also change it in the html to value="3" rather then value="f3"

but i need to access it as f3 and not 3, why does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

The dot is not the [string concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators) operator, but the [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). You want

```
level_prices['f'+i] = i;
```

`'f'.i` gets the literal "i" property of the string object, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you concatenate strings with `+` instead of `.`

Try:

```
level_prices['f'+i] = i;
```

Edit: updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BkGxq/2/